# Python Selenium--Locate a Div ID

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have to click on an image of a dropdown arrow in order to select an item that will populate the input box.Both of them are refered into the dev id:decision. I need your help in order to make my python code to click the image of the arrow and to select a decision. YOu can see in the images what the event of clicking the arrow make.

At least i was looking for a solution to input the text in the input box, but i can't locate properly the input box. I tried with class or xpath and still i can't locate it.
The input class of the input box is pdl_control, but when i used that i got the text populated into another input box in the form.

----Later Edit. The input is not working properly. I have to select the elements from the dropdown list :( If you can help me, I would owe you a lot.
Thank you in advance!!!

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4nlr.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx0Fz.png)

Comment: Can you add some more line in the HTML till second drop down. The existing code is for first drop down which is to select equals, not equals, etc.

Comment: Murthi, I added the code in images, as Firefox didn't allow me to copy the code and to paste it as the html in the pictures. I could paste it, but the result would be a mess in strings...Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving the answer to this question is not that straightforward.
You have only provided the HTML where there are two input boxes and one anchor tag which has an image as the hyperlink.

The **href** provides the link destination. In your HTML it is set to "#", that means on clicking the image, the event will be occurring on the same page.

The anchor tag has the on click event handler:

**"return MultiSelectPDL_TogglePDL(event)"**

The information which you have provided is not sufficient. You have to provide the complete HTML so that I can help you with this question.

Comment: Thank you Monika! I've added the html for that row.

Comment: Hi Monika! I located them with xpath. Thanks to firebug and firepath.

Comment: Monika, still need help on this. I added the code in images, as Firefox didn't allow me to copy the code and to paste it as the html in the pictures. I could paste it, but the result would be a mess in strings...Thank you in advance!